# Swift: UIPanGesture get location horizontally of view

Tags: ios, swift, gesture

ja a gesture that is on the view that vertical black in the photo.

I want to know its location at the level of the screen, because I want to execute a function if for example I slide the view to the right at more than half of the center of the screen

code:

```
@objc func detectPan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    switch recognizer.state {
    case .began:
        self.startingConstant = self.centerConstraint.constant
    case .changed:
        let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        self.centerConstraint.constant = self.startingConstant - translation.x

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

[Fist image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDjCx.png)

[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usUyN.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert coordinates (points and frames) between views as long as they are on the same hierarchy. You have two methods `convert(:to:)` and `convert(:from:)`.

In your case you seem to want to convert location in your view to screen which is your key window `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow`.

So in general the point on screen is `let pointOnScreen = myView.convert(pointInMyView, to: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow)`.

So in your case:

```
let myView = self.view
let pointInMyView = recognizer.locationInView(myView)
let pointOnScreen = myView.convert(pointInMyView, to: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow)

let isViewGestureOnRightSideOfTheScreen = pointOnScreen.x > UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.frame.midX
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get point via

```
func transform(for translation : CGPoint) -> CGAffineTransform {
        let moveBy = CGAffineTransform(translationX: translation.x, y: translation.y) 
        return moveBy
    }

@IBAction func setPanGesture(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .changed:
                let translation = sender.translation(in: view)
                let translationView = transform(for: translation)
                print(translationView)
    case .ended:
               let translation = sender.translation(in: view)
               let translationView = transform(for: translation)
               print(translationView)
    default:
            break
    }
}
```